# Ansible Handler and when condition

Tags: ansible

I am trying to find a logic to check if the service is running, if Not Running, then start it. Below is the logic I have written, but for some reason the notify is not calling the handler?

```yaml
    ---
    - name: Executing the play to start the service
      hosts: nodes
      become: yes
      gather_facts: False
    
      tasks:
    
      - name: Executing the Shell task to check the status of the wso2 instance
        shell: myMsg=$(sudo service wso2esb status| grep Active | awk '{print $3}');if [[ $myMsg == "(dead)" ]]; then echo "Not Running";else echo "Running";fi
        ignore_errors: yes
        register: result
        notify: handl
        when: result.stdout == "Not Running"  (I even tried 'changed_when', but the same error)
    
      handlers:
      - name: handl
        service: name=wso2esb state=started
```

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/hosts.sit start.yml -b -k
SSH password:

PLAY [Executing the play to start the wso2 service] ***********************************************

    TASK [Executing the Shell task to check the status of the instance] *******************************
    fatal: [mpstest01]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'result.stdout == \"Not Running\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (result.stdout == \"Not Running\"): **'result' is undefined**\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/ansible1/start.yml': line 9, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Executing the Shell task to check the status of the instance\n    ^ here\n"}
    ...ignoring
    
    PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************
    mpstest01                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 0):

That all seems unnecessary. You don't need to "check if the service is running, if Not Running, then start it"; that's exactly what the service module does. Just put the `service` module in a task, and don't bother with the handler:

```
  - name: start service if it isn't already running
    service: name=wso2esb state=started
```

Although I would prefer YAML syntax rather than the key=value syntax:

```
  - name: start service if it isn't already running
    service:
      name: wso2esb
      state: started
```

In any case, the `service` module will check if the service is running, and if not, it will start it.

Comment: another question regarding service module with "stopped". If the service is not stopping for some reason, will the service module kill it? or should I need to add a logic to kill the service if not stopped for certain period of time.

Comment: That partly depends on your service manager. If you're using a `systemd` based system, then a service should ultimately be killed `-9` if it won't stop normally.